# If ES6's class static method's this binds to the class, why does this return NaN?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, static-methods

```
class Circle {
    constructor() {
        this.width = 2;
        this.height = 3;
    }
    
    static area() {
        return this.width * this.height
    }
} 

console.log(Circle.area()) // NaN
```

I learned that the static method of Class has this bind to the Class itself, not the Instance's new object.
So I expected Cicle.area() to return 6, which is from (2 * 3). But the actual outcome returns NaN. I cannot find why.

Comment: _"why does this return NaN?"_... because `undefined * undefined` is `NaN`

Comment: Please [edit] and explain what you expect the result to be instead and why.

Comment: "*I learned that the static method of Class has this bind to the Class itself, not the Instance's new object.*" - so you know that `Circle.width` and `Circle.height` are `undefined`, because `Circle` is the class and not a `new Circle()` instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your constructor binds to an instance of the class.  That's where `this.height` and `this.width` are stored (on an instance of the class).

Static methods bind to the class and there is no static `height` or `width` property on the class itself.  Thus, you get NaN when you try to multiply two existing `undefined` values.

In this case, if you want `area` to be a static method, you would have to pass the height and width to it since it is not bound to any instance that has an existing `height` or `width`.

```
class Rectangle {
    static area(height, width) {
        return width * height;
    }
} 

console.log(Rectangle.area(10, 6));
```

Or, if you want to use the instance height and width, then `area` needs to be an instance method, not a static method.

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(height, width) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    
    area() {
        return this.width * this.height;
    }
} 

let rect = new Rectangle(10, 6);
console.log(rect.area()) // 60
```

Note: I converted the example to a Rectangle class because I'm not sure what height and width mean for a circle.